# Testing Google's ClientLogin

Tags: google-api

I have a WPF form that uses ClientLogin to log a user into their Google account.

Specifically, I would like to test my CAPTCHA handling routing.  I can't seem to get my account to generate a CAPTCHA.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reliably get the Google ClientLogin to ask for a CAPTCHA challenge for testing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just spent quite a while trying to do exactly the same thing.

I found the answer here:

http://roobasoft.com/blog/2008/09/20/force-googles-clientlogin-to-require-a-captcha/

Basically you have to spam the ClientLogin service with bad credentials for a valid user email until it responds with a captcha request.

The page above provides a ruby script to do this, implement in a language of your choice!

cheers,

Pete

Comment: Looks like that link is now dead, for posterity: the ruby script is still alive here https://gist.github.com/bricooke/11820 and the blog page can be found here http://web.archive.org/web/20120514135854/http://roobasoft.com/blog/2008/09/20/force-googles-clientlogin-to-require-a-captcha/